# Using SQLite in Ionic Framework

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

My Ionic app should store all the data (more than 300 records) locally. I decided to use [`SQLitePlugin`](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).

I'm trying to make a solution how to:

1. create a table and insert rows at the first app launch.
2. update the data when a user installed the new version of my app and first launched it.

The question is: **Is there any "off-the-shelf" solution how to achieve these?** If not, which best practices are there?

---

In the native android there is useful class [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) with `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` callbacks. I can't find anything similar for Ionic framework.

Answer (score 0):

I believe que all solutions are manual. There is nothing like the native android. To know when was first app launch, could you to test the existence of your DB / tables / data. You can use Local Storage to persist data (or DB), like the version number, and with the aid of the plugin `cordova-plugin-app-version` test if the version has changed or when eas first app launch.